# Auto connect user with fos user bundle / symfony 2

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to auto connect a user after a subscription (my subscription method is in AJAX).

I have something like :

```
// Creation of $user + setters of $user
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$userManager->updateUser($user, true, true, true);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

// Connection of my user here
```

EDIT :

I want to do this in PHP of course and not in JS with a new AJAX request.

EDIT 2 :

I maybe find something. Just trying it now :

```
$this->authenticateUser($user);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles()); 
$context = $this->get('security.context'); 
$context->setToken($token);
```

Comment: I used your code + a little modification with the second argument of the `UsernamePasswordToken` function and it's working like a charm :

`$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
                        $context = $this->get('security.context');
                        $context->setToken($token);`

Comment: Thank you very much by the way :-D

Comment: I need to wait 37 seconds more :-)